# por que no me sube el archivo de imagen y no se visualiza?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

tengo el siguiente codigo fuente, el problema es que no se por que no se visualiza ni tampoco se suben las imagenes. me indica error de extencion de archivo. uso windows 7 con xampp php 5.3

```
   <?php
include_once "includes/mysql_conex.php";
$archivo = $_POST['archivo'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
        $useruid2 = mysqli_query($conexion, 'INSERT INTO usuarios_registro (foto_perfil) values(\''.$archivo.'\')');
        // if (mysqli_num_rows($useruid2) == 0)
        if ($useruid2 == 0)
            die('Dato 1.');
        else 
        {
        $imagen_vista = mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT * FROM usuarios_registro ORDER BY RowID DESC  LIMIT 1');
        $RowID =(mysqli_fetch_array($imagen_vista));
        $id_insert = $RowID['0'];
        echo "<center><h2>Entro el RowID <font color='red'>".$RowID['0']."</font> con ese numero</h2></center>";
        if($_FILES['archivo']['error']>0){
            die('<font color=red>No se subio archivo.</font>');
        }else{
        //die('Entro 1');//test de entrada para descomentar
            $permitidos = array("image/jpg","image/png","image/gif");
            $limite_kb = 5120;
                if(in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"],$permitidos))
                {
                    if(in_array($_FILES['archivo']['type']['size'] < $limite_kb))
                    {
                        die('Entro 2');//test de entrada para descomentar
                        $ruta='./images/'.$id_insert.'/';
                        $archivo = $ruta.$_FILES['archivo']['name'];
                                if(!file_exists($ruta)){
                                // die('Entro 3');//test de entrada para descomentar
                                mkdir($ruta);
                                }
                                    if(!file_exists($archivo)){
                                    $resultado =@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],$archivo);
                                        if($resultado){
                                        // die('Entro 4');//test de entrada para descomentar
                                        echo"archivo guardado";
                                        }else{
                                        // die('Entro 5');//test de entrada para descomentar
                                        echo"Error al guardar archivo";
                                        }

                                    }else{
                                    die('el archivo ya existe');
                                    }
                    }else{
                    die('archivo pesado');
                    }
                }else{
                die('Extencion de archivo no permitido');
                }
        }


        }
}

        $imagen_vista_src = mysqli_query($conexion, 'SELECT * FROM usuarios_registro ORDER BY RowID DESC  LIMIT 1');
        $vita =(mysqli_fetch_array($imagen_vista_src)); 
echo    "images/".$vita['0']."/".$vita['foto_perfil'];  
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method="POST">
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td rowspan="1"><img src="<?php "images/".$vita['foto_perfil'];?>" width=100 height=100></td><td></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<td></td><td></td>
<td></td><td></td>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">Subir Foto de Perfil</td>
<td colspan="8"><input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo"accept="image/*"></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">Name</td>
<td colspan="8"><?php echo $namefirs; ?></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">last Name</td>
<td colspan="8"><?php echo $namefirs; ?></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">Documento</td>
<td colspan="8"><?php echo $namefirs; ?></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">Wallet Bitcoin</td>
<td colspan="8"><?php echo $namefirs; ?></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">Wallet Etherium</td>
<td colspan="8"><?php echo $namefirs; ?></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">Wallet litecoin</td>
<td colspan="8"><?php echo $namefirs; ?></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">PayPal</td>
<td colspan="8"><?php echo $namefirs; ?></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="1">Uphold</td>
<td colspan="8"><?php echo $namefirs; ?></td>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Actualizar" name="submit" /></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: creo que debes modificar la capacidad de subida en xampp, si bien recuerdo es en el archivo ini

Comment: lol se me habia olvidado cuel es que es la linea?

Comment: sera es? pero ya dice upload_max_filesize = 128M me imagino son megas no bites ni kilobites

Comment: de todas formas el error es en extencion de archivo

Answer (score 0):

Ten cuidado, no es `image/jpg` es `image/jpeg`. Por tanto, debería de ser:

```php
 $permitidos = array("image/jpeg","image/png","image/gif");
```

En cualquier caso, para poder ayudarte se necesita algo más de información. Por ejemplo, ¿ puedes añadirnos el resultado de la siguiente línea...

```php
print_r($_FILES["archivo"]["type"]);
```

si la colocas antes del if de comprobación de la extensión ?.

Comment: amigo fijate el form falta algo vital para que funcione termina en algom como "/from-data"